# 'Error converting value' when JSON DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, compact-framework

I have a piece of code which I can't find the issue in. I'm working with Visual Studio 2008 and developing using .Net CF 3.5.

I receive the following JSON string:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "DbServerInstance": "Ej8/Pz9ubnldPx9ePxk=",
    "DbServerUser": "Px4/Ez8/Pz8/DT9OfBo=",
    "DbServerPassword": "TWsYRiQ/PyM/ZT8/PzJZ",
    "DbServerDatabase": "PwVRczpEPz8aPz8/DnRD",
    "UserManualURL": "Pz8rNUd2PxdAPzM/Uxw/Wg==",
    "ApplicationName": "PzwAAm5MTks/Pz0obD9P"
  }
]
```

I also created the following classes:

```
public class JSONResponse{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DbServerInstance")]
    public string dbServerInstance { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DbServerUser")]
    public string dbServerUser { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DbServerPassword")]
    public string dbServerPassword { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DbServerDatabase")]
    public string dbServerDatabase { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserManualURL")]
    public string userManualURL { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ApplicationName")]
    public string applicationName { get; set; }
}

public class JSONArray
{
    public IList<JSONResponse> Params { get; set; }
}
```

I try to deserialize using the following command:

```
List<JSONResponse> rp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONResponse>>(returnString);
```

This give me the error:

**{"Error converting value \"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 1,\r\n    \"DbServerInstance\": \"Ej8/Pz9ubnldPx9ePxk=\",\r\n    \"DbServerUser\": \"Px4/Ez8/Pz8/DT9OfBo=\",\r\n    \"DbServerPassword\": \"TWsYRiQ/PyM/ZT8/PzJZ\",\r\n    \"DbServerDatabase\": \"PwVRczpEPz8aPz8/DnRD\",\r\n    \"UserManualURL\": \"Pz8rNUd2PxdAPzM/Uxw/Wg==\",\r\n    \"ApplicationName\": \"PzwAAm5MTks/Pz0obD9P\"\r\n  }\r\n]\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[louisapp.JSONResponse]'."}    System.Exception {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException}**

I searched, but can't find the issue and as I'm quite new to JSON, my knowledge is limited. Any input would be appreciated.

Edit:
The code which is calling the web api:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: echo out `returnString`. Are you sure that `\r\n` and stuff is being properly turned into new lines? It looks like you're trying to pass the *escaped* version to `DeserializeObject`

Comment: What do you mean by 'echo out'? Do you mean that I should 'unescape' it somehow?

Comment: I tried your exact code with your classes and it seems to be working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6hvtv8 .The only exception I feel is that your `returnString` is not giving correct data as `JSON`. You would need to investigate into that.

Comment: What do you mean, that returnString is not correct data as JSON? That it's corrupt? I wrote a service which is returning this JSON string, using Newtonsoft aswell and when I call the service from a browser, it shows up perfectly. I have a feeling that I need to clean up the escape chars somehow, but it's now really happening

Comment: When I inspect the returnString, this is the value: [\r\n {\r\n \"id\": 1,\r\n \"DbServerInstance\": \"Ej8/Pz9ubnldPx9ePxk=\",\r\n \"DbServerUser\": \"Px4/Ez8/Pz8/DT9OfBo=\",\r\n \"DbServerPassword\": \"TWsYRiQ/PyM/ZT8/PzJZ\",\r\n \"DbServerDatabase\": \"PwVRczpEPz8aPz8/DnRD\",\r\n \"UserManualURL\": \"Pz8rNUd2PxdAPzM/Uxw/Wg==\",\r\n \"ApplicationName\": \"PzwAAm5MTks/Pz0obD9P\"\r\n }\r\n].

Comment: @user9671207 You can validate if your `JSON` string is correct here: https://jsonlint.com/. Also can you show me how you are generating your `returnString`? You can try this method also: `Regex.Unescape(returnString)` which will return a new string with no ecapes, even \n \t etc, are removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `returnString` is not in right json format. Looking at the exception the `returnString` having additional double quotes at begining and end `\"[` `]\"`

I have tried the same example and it throws the above exception

```
string returnString = "\"[\r\n {\r\n \"id\": 1,\r\n \"DbServerInstance\": \"Ej8/Pz9ubnldPx9ePxk=\",\r\n \"DbServerUser\": \"Px4/Ez8/Pz8/DT9OfBo=\",\r\n \"DbServerPassword\": \"TWsYRiQ/PyM/ZT8/PzJZ\",\r\n \"DbServerDatabase\": \"PwVRczpEPz8aPz8/DnRD\",\r\n \"UserManualURL\": \"Pz8rNUd2PxdAPzM/Uxw/Wg==\",\r\n \"ApplicationName\": \"PzwAAm5MTks/Pz0obD9P\"\r\n }\r\n]\"";

List<JSONResponse> rp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONResponse>>(returnString);
```

After removing additional quotes, it started working

```
string returnString = "[\r\n {\r\n \"id\": 1,\r\n \"DbServerInstance\": \"Ej8/Pz9ubnldPx9ePxk=\",\r\n \"DbServerUser\": \"Px4/Ez8/Pz8/DT9OfBo=\",\r\n \"DbServerPassword\": \"TWsYRiQ/PyM/ZT8/PzJZ\",\r\n \"DbServerDatabase\": \"PwVRczpEPz8aPz8/DnRD\",\r\n \"UserManualURL\": \"Pz8rNUd2PxdAPzM/Uxw/Wg==\",\r\n \"ApplicationName\": \"PzwAAm5MTks/Pz0obD9P\"\r\n }\r\n]";

List<JSONResponse> rp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONResponse>>(returnString);
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. You're right. Do you have any idea why this "\ is added to the string? The json string is created using Newtonsoft JSON in .Net and returned via an httprequest. If possible, I would prefer to fix the issue at the source iso clipping the string. Thanks!

Comment: The possible reason could be double serialization. Just check the code whether the serialization applied twice.

Comment: On the server side it seems ok. I just debugged it and the result is a clean JSON string. When calling the web api directly in the browser it also looks clean: [{"id":1,"DbServerInstance":"Ej8/Pz9ubnldPx9ePxk=","DbServerUser":"Px4/Ez8/Pz8/DT9OfBo=","DbServerPassword":"TWsYRiQ/PyM/ZT8/PzJZ","DbServerDatabase":"PwVRczpEPz8aPz8/DnRD","UserManualURL":"Pz8rNUd2PxdAPzM/Uxw/Wg==","ApplicationName":"PzwAAm5MTks/Pz0obD9P"}] . I edited the original post with the json request code which I'm using. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: YES! It was double serialization. Thanks a lot for the hints.

Comment: hi @KrishnaVarma, I call another API by : `getUrl = http.xxx.yyy`
`RestClient client = new RestClient(getUrl);`
`RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);`
`var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);`
But it give me additional quotes like your first example, how can I remove it (Im not use serialization so I can't check)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<JSONResponse> rp =    jserial.Deserialize<List<JSONResponse>>(returnString);
```

Try this one its working for us fine here

Answer (score 0):

Additional, Double serialization occurs when you serialize anonymous type.

```
var anonymous  = new { Id = 1, Name = "Any Body" };

var jsonContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anonymous);
return Ok(jsonContent);

Result:  "{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Any Body\"}"
```

If you return direct anonymous

```
return Ok(anonymous);
Result: {"id":1,"name":"Any Body"}
```